# How to do math calculation on each number in a specific column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, math, exp

I imported an Excel file by using `pandas.read_excel()` in Python.
Then I want to do math calculation to each number in a specific column, and generate a new column. But there is an error:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

How can I solve this? Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

N_DATA=pd.read_excel(r"path\datajl.xls",index_col='R')
rchdecay=N_DATA['column_name']
rchdcayf=math.exp(-rchdecay*0.008)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.exp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html):

```
import numpy as np

rchdecay=N_DATA['column_name']
rchdcayf=np.exp(-rchdecay*0.008)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N_DATA = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':[1,2,3]})
print (N_DATA)
   column_name
0            1
1            2
2            3

rchdcayf=np.exp(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008)
print (rchdcayf)
0    0.992032
1    0.984127
2    0.976286
Name: column_name, dtype: float64
```

Or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `math.exp`, but it is slowier:

```
rchdcayf1=(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008).apply(math.exp)
print (rchdcayf1)
0    0.992032
1    0.984127
2    0.976286
Name: column_name, dtype: float64
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=3`

```
In [61]: %timeit (-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008).apply(math.exp)
The slowest run took 5.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 209 µs per loop

In [62]: %timeit np.exp(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008)
The slowest run took 4.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop
```

`len(df)=3k`:

```
In [64]: %timeit np.exp(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008)
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop

In [65]: %timeit (-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008).apply(math.exp)
1000 loops, best of 3: 873 µs per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

N_DATA = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':[1,2,3]})
N_DATA = pd.concat([N_DATA]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

rchdcayf=np.exp(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008)
print (rchdcayf)

rchdcayf1=(-N_DATA['column_name']*0.008).apply(math.exp)
print (rchdcayf1)
```